# Linq query on 3rd child level

Tags: c#, linq

I have following requirement on List of objects.
My class structure is like:

```
  public class Standard
    {
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Student> Students {get;set;}
    }
    
    public class Student
    {
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Hobby> Hobbies {get;set;}
    }
    
    public class Hobby
    {
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}  
    }
```

I want to filter based on Hobbies on following scenarios:

- List of All the Standards with Students who has hobby of Playing Music
- List of All the Standards with Students who has hobby of Singing Songs

Currently I have List available with me with all child classes and details. I am able to do this with ForEach loop but wanted to learn Linq syntax for this scenarios.

Please suggest Linq syntax for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have a collection of `Standard` called `standards`,

> List of All the Standards with Students who has hobby of Playing Music

```
var result = standards.Where(s => s.Students.Any(u => u.Hobbies.Any(h => h.Name == "Playing Music")));
```

> List of All the Standards with Students who has hobby of Singing Songs

```
var result = standards.Where(s => s.Students.Any(u => u.Hobbies.Any(h => h.Name == "Playing Music")));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but Hobbies also has class structure like Hobby.Id and Hobby.Name

Comment: swap `u.Hobbies.Contains("Singing Songs")` for `u.Hobbies.Where(h => h.Name == "Singing Songs")`

Comment: Just do `u.Hobbies.Any(h => h.Name == "Playing Music")` instead of the contains.